# How to process a video's equal parts concurrently in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, parallel-processing, video-processing

There is a video file and four equally divided parts with FFMPEG but i want to process video without cutting them with FFMPEG to be more dynamic. I just want to logically divide a video and send them to `p.map()` function without everytime creating video parts in my project file.
Here is my code ;

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p:
        p.map( function , ['video-0.mp4','video-1.mp4','video-2.mp4','video-3.mp4' ])

def function(video):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    ...
```

Is it possible to send equally determined parts to this function without cutting them ?

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am planning to do  by determining total frames divide them and setting positions but do you mean that i can not send the start-end points to my function or is it possible to process them in this way ?

Comment: No, you cannot access the same video file from multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: I understand, it seems like the only way would be to use buffer then.